# Php not executing system command

Tags: php, ocr, tesseract

I have downloaded Tesseract OCR, installed it on windows and set its path variable and test it as well.
https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php
I have downloaded its php script too and did some basic testing.

```
echo $this->buildTesseractCommand();
exec(trim($this->buildTesseractCommand()));
```

The command

```
echo tesseract C:\xampp\htdocs\OCR\test\images\hello.png C:\xampp\htdocs\OCR\test\temp\29847.txt
```

where hello.png is file to read characters from and 29847.txt is random file generated from cmd in which output is stored. although the same command is working directly through cmd.

But sadly the command is not working through php and no .txt file is generated , but when I paste the same in my command prompt, it works and file is generated.

I have tried `system()`, `exec()` and `passthru()` functions to run command but its not working in any :(

Any idea how to run it or any alternatives ?

Comment: In php configuration file, the above command are commented, for safety...see configuration in php.ini

Comment: I run basic command like exec('mkdir abc'); and it worked :(

Comment: Does your command literally have "echo" at the front like you show it?  Try removing it.